# How does an executable function properly with multiple users simultaneously using the same program without the program crashing?

Tags: c#

I have not had to create an executable for multiple users, and I am wondering how to let the program know that this instance of the class is a new users input, or rather that the program should start with a clean slate of incoming input for the program to handle. Example, say I create photo upload program, and I have multiple users using the program at the same time. How will the program know that this file is for one user and the other for another user. Does this have to do with threading? Or is this just a simple case of created non-static variables?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate instances of a program do not share *anything* with each-other (except for truly global resoruces like the filesystem).

`static` fields are per-AppDomain, not per-computer.